# How to get the intermediate debug logs of cwl-runner while running a workflow?

Tags: common-workflow-language

How do I get the logs of all the steps in a cwl-runner, that I see on the terminal. I want to be able to store these logs somewhere, so that I can use the outputs of intermediate steps.

Is there a flag that I can use while running cwl-runner? I tried different flags like tmp-prefix, --output-dir and etc, but somehow they are not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

`--writeLogs=$PWD/logs` will dump your logs into the logs folder in your current working directory.